# Is the ring $C(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic with a proper subring?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $ X$ be a topological space. The set $C(X)$ is all continuous, real valued functions on $X$, so that $C(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{X}$.

Define:

$C^* (X) = \{ f \in C(X) \vert \quad  f\quad  is \quad bounded \}$.

My questions are:

> 1:The ring $C(\mathbb{R})$  is isomorphic with a proper
>    subring.[Consider the function that are constant on $[ 0 , 1]$.] But
>    $C(\mathbb{R})$ has no  proper summand.
>
> 2: In $C(X)$ ( or $C^{*} (X)$ ), all positive units have the same
>    number of square roots.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, it should read “$C(ℝ)$ has no proper *factor*” in the sense that there are no subrings $A$ and $B$ of $C(ℝ)$ such that $C(ℝ) \cong A × B$. As $C(ℝ)$ is a real vector space, it has plenty proper summands (namely as real vector spaces).

Finally, what are positive units?

Comment: For the roots question and the no summand see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2531575/4280) (class mate?) The hint voor 1. is quite clear. Do you see the ring isomorphism between them?

Comment: @k.stm a positive unit $f$ in $C(X)$ is such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in X$. It's a unit, as it has $\frac{1}{f}$ as an inverse in $C(X)$.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma It seems that the question has been deleted. Thank you once again for the answer to the question.